# Servlet mapping direct JSP files rather than using a Servlet to manage the URL requests

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am redoing the URL mapping structure within my Java web application. I am trying to find the most efficient and proper way to map the servelets and resources to their proper URLs.

There are two strategies that I have been able to create, but I am not sure which is more efficient.

**Mapping All urls to one Servlet which Handles the requests**

In this case I have a Servlet named "URL", with the following servlet mapping:

```
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>url</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The url Servlet is set up like such as an example and works fine:

```
String task = request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getContextPath().length());
if ("/home".equals(task)){
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/home.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

The problem I initially had with this that all the static resources such as JS, Images, etc... weren't served. I had the option to create separate directories for the static content as a solution, but off the top of my head I switched to mapping it all directly in the web.xml.

**Mapping it all directly in the web.xml.**

In this case the url patterns are directly mapped to the JSPs and Servlets like so:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
  <jsp-file>/jsp/Home.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Example:

```
localhost:8080/home <- home.jsp

localhost:8080/about <- about.jsp

localhost:8080/login <- doLogin servlet
```

Are these bad? Which would be a more efficient and proper way to map the urls to their intended JSP files and Servlets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use a combination of both, I define all the static pages in web.xml and right at the end of the web.xml, I create a catch-all that will handle dynamic pages.

So home, about, login, etc are all static pages, define them in web.xml
Something like account/abc and blog/some-random-article is handled dynamically.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>NotFound</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.site.PageNotFoundServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>NotFound</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If in your servlet code, if you don't know how to handle the url, in other words the url is something like /asdfadfasdf which you don't handle, throw a 404 back, if the url starts with /blog (from /blog/random-article), go to the blog page with the random-article as the content.

Answer (score 1):

The case of "**home.jsp**" is not same here

```
 RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/home.jsp")
```

and

```
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
  <jsp-file>/jsp/**Home.jsp**</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```